# Check checkbox on page with specific class

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

So I've had enough of this one page, I always have to check a checkbox if I want to send a private message, and when I send a message, I want it to be private always. So I decided to try making a google chrome extension about it. So I've created the default files, `manifest.json`, and `popup.html`, but I can't get it working.

What am I doing wrong?

`Manifest.json`:

```
{
  "name": "xxx",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "description": "Automaattinen yksityiskommentointi.",
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  }
}
```

`popup.html`:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>XXX</title>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
Moi
</body>
</html>
```

and `script.js`:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.private-checkbox').prop('checked', true);   
});
```

It would be too easy, right? I bet that this would only check the checkbox on the popup, but I want to check checkboxed in the tabs I open.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked for me with following change in popup.html

Download jquery.min.js and add it in your package as shown

**Use**

```
<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
```

*instead of*

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

> Only local script and and object resources are loaded

Script and object resources can only be loaded from the extension's package, not from the web at large. This ensures that your extension only executes the code you've specifically approved, preventing an active network attacker from maliciously redirecting your request for a resource.

**Updated Manifest.json**

```
{
  "name": "xxx",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "description": "Automaattinen yksityiskommentointi.",
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
"content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["http://www.facebook.com/*"],
      "js": ["jquery.min.js","myscript.js"]
    }
  ]
    }
```

**myscript.js**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.private-checkbox').prop('checked', true);   
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the local file info, but it still only checks the checkbox in the popup.html, and I want it to check **every** checkbox with class .private-checkbox.

Comment: "and I want it to check every checkbox with class .private-checkbox", Can i know where are all these check boxes you are referring to appear? in popup.html or ??

Comment: for example, facebook.com or a similar site in the internet. So outside the extension.

Comment: i have updated solution, you need to use content scripts for any thing out side extension

Comment: Yeah, btw, your json has an extra comma. But my jQuery script isn't working. It doesn't exist I think, as I tried alert("moi");

Comment: you need to add jquery explicitly as i have shown in manifest, download jquery and include it in content scripts; it will work. i have removed trailing comma from my answer also